# How do I increment a value server side nested in an array using Node, MongoDB and Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am trying to create a route that will update a specific value in an object in a nested array. I am getting a 404 error in my node console. I am almost certain that this is not the way to do it but my code will give an idea of what I want to achieve:

```
router.put('/getProfile/:profile_id/addWin'), function (req, res) {
UserProfile.findOne({
    UserID : req.params.profile_id //Find the correct Profile
}, function (err, profile) {
    if (err)
        res.send(err);

    profile.Drafts.findByID({ //Find the corrct Draft in the Profile
        _id : req.body.DraftID
    }, function (err, draft) {

        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        draft.Wins += 1; //Increment the wins
    })

    profile.save(function (err) { //Save the profile
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json({
            message : 'Win added!'
        });
    });
});}
```

this is the error in the console:

```
PUT /api/getProfile/575ecce6924295bc21000005/addWin 404 5.128 ms - -
```

The route should find the correct profile (this works in my other routes), using the `profile_id`, then access the `Drafts array` and find the correct Draft and `increment the wins`. How do I achieve this?

In my request body I just send the `DraftID and the profileID` as parameter and is stored in a UserID property in the profile object.

This is my first attempt ever at the `MEAN stack` so I am not comfortable yet.

Comment: Just a tip: `POST /api/getProfile/5...`  and `router.put('/getProfile/:profile_id/addWin')` => `POST != PUT`

Comment: Thanks you're right, I copied the wrong message as I was playing around with put/post. Edited :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must pass the callback function(req,res) as second parameter in the router like this:   (no closing th function after the url)

```
router.put('/getProfile/:profile_id/addWin', function (req, res) {
UserProfile.findOne({
    UserID : req.params.profile_id //Find the correct Profile
}, function (err, profile) {
    if (err)
        res.send(err);

    profile.Drafts.findByID({ //Find the corrct Draft in the Profile
        _id : req.body.DraftID
    }, function (err, draft) {

        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        draft.Wins += 1; //Increment the wins
    })

    profile.save(function (err) { //Save the profile
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json({
            message : 'Win added!'
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! However, now I have a whole new world of problems haha. I think they might be for a different question.